# Heroku Worker not appearing

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, discord.py

I have deployed my Python discord bot to Heroku and enabled automatic deploys, but when I go to resources, I don't see the worker anywhere even though I've deployed it.
Also, I'm using Github not the CLI

Log:

```
    2020-11-15T14:53:25.242489+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user tristan910@gmail.com
2020-11-15T14:53:25.242489+00:00 app[api]: Set DISCORD_TOKEN config vars by user tristan910@gmail.com
2020-11-15T14:54:03.117936+00:00 app[api]: Remove DISCORD_TOKEN config vars by user tristan910@gmail.com
2020-11-15T14:54:03.117936+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user tristan910@gmail.com
2020-11-15T14:54:12.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user tristan910@gmail.com
2020-11-15T14:54:42.965488+00:00 app[api]: Release v9 created by user tristan910@gmail.com
2020-11-15T14:54:42.965488+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 7ca5f9b8 by user tristan910@gmail.com
2020-11-15T14:54:55.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-11-15T14:55:17.115611+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=trashrpg-bot.herokuapp.com request_id=ef04e10f-3f2e-4e5b-a667-2eab578c2b40 fwd="24.101.242.186" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-15T14:55:18.690316+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=trashrpg-bot.herokuapp.com request_id=3aeabd82-91df-4c21-8bb9-4398df1625a7 fwd="24.101.242.186" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

(no procfile that I know of)

Comment: Please post the log and Procfile code of your application

Comment: @HarshanaSerasinghe I couldn't find any procfile, because I was using a template when I made this, but I pasted the log in the question message(too big to fit in comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be because you need to create a `procfile` inside the repository.
This is where you write what you want the worker to do. For example, you need to create a new file named `Procfile`, and inside you need to write:

```
worker: python "Your main`s file name here"
```

At least, it worked this way for me when I deployed a Discord bot on Heroku.

Comment: It worked and showed me the worker button, but when I did it, the bot didn't go online. That part could be an error of my code, but I'm not sure

Comment: Yeah it might be an error inside the code because as far as i know that's how you can do it.Also i saw in a tutorial written instead of ":" a "=", but i haven't tried that